# Using SSH to access JupyterLab on GCP Doesn't Work Yet

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, jupyter-lab

I would like to ssh myself into a Jupyter Lab notebook on GCP. For that, I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/ssh-access) guide by Google.

I already have CloudSDK installed on my PC, and when I type `gcloud compute ssh --project $PROJECT_ID ...` and all the rest, it throws the following error on my terminal:

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
>
> - Invalid value ' test-gpu'. Values must match the following regular expression:
>   'a-z?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}

Unfortunately, I do not really understand this error message, as my instance-name is called "test-gpu", which was a perfectly valid name when creating the instance.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: run 'glcoud auth list' to see that user is authorized to do the SSH. To authorized use command 'gcloud auth login' and try again.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a space in the beginning of the name of your instance, please remove and try again.

Comment: Hi jabbson, actually, I don't: I write **export INSTANCE_name=test-gpu** without any spaces. Or does it have to be **export INSTANCE_name="test-gu"**?

Comment: My suggestion was based on the output of the error you quoted. I don't think the quotes should make a difference, but since you are following the guide, I'd most definitely try to put the name in quotes, or just run the gcloud command without variables by directly specifying the project_id, zone and instance_name a la:
```gcloud compute ssh --project jabbson-project-1 --zone us-central1-a some-test-notebook -- -L 8080:localhost:8080```

Answer (score 0):

Able to reproduce the the issue in my Windows machine while trying to access the notebook as per the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/notebooks/docs/ssh-access) as per below command:

```
set PROJECT_ID="my-project-id"
set ZONE="my-zone"
set INSTANCE_NAME="my-instance"
gcloud compute ssh --project $PROJECT_ID --zone $ZONE $INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:

Invalid value 'my-instance'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'a-z?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}
```

However, while use the command as like below in windows machine it's work as intended:

```
$gcloud compute ssh --project my-test-project --zone us-west1-b instance-name -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```

At the same time, able to access the instance from the Chromebook using the below mentioned command:

```
$gcloud compute ssh --project $PROJECT_ID --zone $ZONE $INSTANCE_NAME -- -L 8080:localhost:8080
```